# Reference of generalized isometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, automorphism-groups

I'm wondering if these objects have a name or are studied.  No one around me knows, so I thought to ask here.

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be $C^2$-diffeomoprhism, and fix $p \geq 0$, is there a name/known characterization of the diffeomorphisms satisfying
$$
d(\Phi(x),y)-d(x,\Phi^{-1}(y)) \in o(d(x,y)^p)?
$$

For example, and isometry solves this for $p=0$ (exactly), but what about in general?

Comment: This is not clear to me why such a class of diffeomorphisms should be interesting. Any motivation supporting the definition of this class?

Comment: Yes it is near isometric

Comment: I am not convinced. The definition lacks certain homogeneity. If $\Phi$ satisfies it, then it is not clear that $\Phi_v=\Phi+v$ ($v$-constant vector) satisfies it. There are many conditions that are satisfied by isometries and not every such condition is forth studying. You need a deeper motivation than just the fact isometries satisfy it.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz hmmm I took some time to think about that, and its true; very interesting point!